# How to create a C-string containing binary raster-data of a ppm image

Tags: python, c, arrays, string

I have a little problem concerning string generation in C.
The following code snippet is part of a C Extension for a Python/Tkinter app which generates images (mandelbrot, gradients and such). Before anyone asks: I don't want to power up Photoshop for such a simple task - overkill...

The problem I'm having is at the end of the snippet in the last for-loop.
This function generates a PPM image file for further processing. The main goal is to generate a string containing the raster data in binary format and pass that string back to Python and then to Tkinter image data to have a preview of the result.

At the moment I write a file to disk which is pretty slow. 
The iterator-function returns a pointer to a RGB-array.
If I now write every single color-value to the file using

```
fputc(col[0], outfile)
```

it works (the section which is commeted out).
To get closer to my main goal I tried to merge the three color values into a string and write that into the file.
When I run that code from my Python app, I end up with a file containing just the header.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction? Tha whole C-thing is pretty new to me - so I'm pretty much stuck here...

```
static PyObject* py_mandelbrotppm(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    //get filename from argument
    char *filename;
    PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &filename);
    //---------- open file for writing and create header
    FILE *outfile = NULL;
    outfile = fopen(filename, "w");

    //---------- create ppm header
    char header[17];
    sprintf(header,"P6\n%d %d\n255\n", dim_x, dim_y);
    fputs(header, outfile);
    //---------- end of header generation

    for(int y = 0;y<dim_y;y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0;x<dim_x;x++)
        {
            int *col = iterator(x,y);
            char pixel[3] = {col[0], col[1], col[2]};
            fputs(pixel, outfile);

            /*
            for(int i = 0;i<3;i++)
            {
                fputc(pixel[i], outfile);
            }
            */
        }
    }
    fclose(outfile);
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

Comment: I would write a pure Python version first: you could use numpy arrays to manipulate the data (or array.array, or manually generate binary buffer), then convert them to an Image (Pillow: `Image.fromarray`, `Image.fromstring`) and display them in Tkinter (`ImageTk.PhotoImage`).

Comment: That's what I did in the first place but image calculations took a huge amount of time in pure python. So I decided to go for a C extension because the C API is already part of Python and pure C code is extremely fast. This gave me huge speed bump when calculating images... The main goal is to have the image in memory and not on disk. That's why I wanted to use a large string with the raster data to do further processing and write to disk when I hit the save-button ...

Comment: If you have a pure Python version that is slow for your needs then you could also ask how to speed it up e.g., a carefully placed type declaration on an existing Python function can make it  run 100x times faster when compiled with [Cython](http://cython.org/) or jitted with Numba (you still need to know C to understand and efficiently change the code).

Comment: For in-process data exchange, you could pass arrays, images directly (it is easy to convert them both ways).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - Passing the image as array/string is exactly what I am looking for... Afaik a string in C is an array of chars. But everytime I try to write the RGB-chars to an array I get corrupted files or even crashes...

Comment: An image/array is probably just a pointer at C level. You don't need to convert them to a string just to call another function. If you need to pass data to C code that doesn't know about images/arrays then pass their data buffers instead (it is *much* easier if you use typed memoryviews from Cython).

Comment: I presume you are aware that `fputs()` and quite a few other related functions will stop on the first 0 byte they see. If you have a pixel that has, for example, a 0-valued R component, it's quite possible the G and B components won't even be written. This is likely to be ... problematic ... in images that might quite often have pixels with 0 bytes present in them somewhere. You might need to re-think your design somewhat, unless you can guarantee that this will never happen...

Comment: @twalberg: I totally missed that... As said before - I'm new to C. I re-wrote the extension in that way, that only the image calculations are done in C. The functions return a tuple (RGB) for the current pixel. If I build the picture in python using plain text (P3) the whole process takes about 6 times longer than the C Version. So my goal should be to create that tuple in C and return that. I'll give that a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems with your new code.

`pixel` is missing a null terminator (and space for it). Fix it like this:

```
char pixel[4] = {col[0], col[1], col[2], '\0'};
```

---

But I'll let you in on a little secret. Putting a bunch of `int`s into an array of `char`s is going to truncate them and do all sorts of weird, squirrly things. Maybe not for `char`-length numbers, but in terms of general style I wouldn't recommend it. Consider this:

```
...
for(int x = 0;x<dim_x;x++){
     int *col = iterator(x,y);
     fprintf(outfile, "%d, %d, %d", col[0], col[1], col[2]);
}
...
```

On the other hand, I'm a little confused as to why `iterator` returns ints when RGB values are from 0-255, which is precisely the range an `unsigned char` has:

```
unsigned char *col = iterator(x,y);
fprintf(outfile, "%u, %u, %u", col[0], col[1], col[2]);
```

Comment: Ok, I get it. But if I use 'sprint()' to a string with size 'x*y*3' instead, and write that string - I get a broken file or crash. I'm trying to skip the file write... But this solution works like a charm so far. THANKS!!!

Comment: @hegoe wait, what? If it's `x*y*3` long, then you're going to have to use a different format specifier string because `'%d, %d, %d'` is 3 ints long.

Comment: @hegoe: How can it work? [ppm format](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html) doesn't allow any delimiters (such as `', '`) between color samples. It should be `fwrite(unsigned_char_pixel, 1, 3, outfile)`

Comment: @Al.Sal sorry, I should have stated out more clearly that I want to use binary format for the file which would be P6 in ppm standard. Somehow this format works better with Tkinter. In plain text formatting I had some strange errors which I couldn't reproduce...

Comment: @Al.Sal: By the way - using what I learned from your answer the actual code is this: `fprintf(outfile, "%c%c%c", col[0], col[1], col[0]);`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian good point. I should have paid more attention to the `ppm` part of the question - I gave a general answer, but it looks like OP was able to adapt if for his purposes.